# Uncaught Error: 'target' is a required option - Svelte

Tags: npm, svelte, rollupjs

I'm building an NPM package for Svelte. With this package I export a couple of simple components:

```js
import SLink from './SLink.svelte';
import SView from './SView.svelte';

export { SLink, SView };
```

This is before bundling them to a minified version using rollup.

Rollup config:

```js
module.exports = {
    input: 'src/router/index.ts',
    output: {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'umd',
        name: 'Router',
        sourcemap: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            format: 'umd',
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
        }),
        resolve(),
        typescript(),
        terser(),
    ],
};
```

`package.json` (minus unnecessary info):

```json
{
    "name": "svelte-dk-router",
    "version": "0.1.29",
    "main": "dist/router.umd.min.js",
    "scripts": {
        "lib": "rollup -c lib.config.js",
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "svelte": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist/router.umd.min.js"
    ],
}
```

When I publish the package and test it, I get this error:

```js
Uncaught Error: 'target' is a required option
    at new SvelteComponentDev (index.mjs:1642)
    at new Home (App.svelte:5)
    at Z (router.umd.min.js:1)
    at N (router.umd.min.js:1)
    at new t.SView (router.umd.min.js:1)
    at create_fragment (App.svelte:5)
    at init (index.mjs:1476)
    at new App (App.svelte:5)
    at main.js:7
    at main.js:9
```

Which seems to be something to do with mounting the component as `target` is used to mount:

```js
const app = new App({ target: document.body })
```

---

The odd thing is, `SLink` on it's own works fine, mounts as it should etc., it's just `SView` that doesn't work.

`SLink`:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { writableRoute, changeRoute } from '../logic';

    export let name: string = undefined,
        path: string = undefined,
        query: Record<string, string> = undefined,
        params: Record<string, string> = undefined;

    let routerActive: boolean;

    writableRoute.subscribe(newRoute => {
        if (newRoute.path === '*') return;
        const matches = (path && path.match(newRoute.regex)) || newRoute.name === name;
        routerActive = matches ? true : false;
    });
</script>

<div
    on:click={() => changeRoute({ name, path, query, params })}
    class={routerActive ? 'router-active' : ''}>
    <slot />
</div>
```

`SView`:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { writableRoute } from '../logic';

    let component: any;

    writableRoute.subscribe(newRoute => (component = newRoute ? newRoute.component : null));
</script>

<svelte:component this={component} />
```

---

I've tried the components uncompiled, as per [these docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte#pkgsvelte), but then the imports don't work.

Anyone have any idea how I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All components in a Svelte tree need to be compiled with the same Svelte compiler (i.e. same `node_modules/svelte`) all at once. This includes components from external libs like what you are trying to achieve. This is what is explained in the docs you've linked.

The `main` field of the `package.json` will expose the compiled components, for usage in a non Svelte app.

You also need a `svelte` field to expose the uncompiled version of the components, for consumption by a Svelte app. You can still export multiple Svelte components from a `.js` file.

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "svelte-dk-router",
    "version": "0.1.29",
    "main": "dist/router.umd.min.js",

    "svelte": "src/index.js",

    "scripts": {
        "lib": "rollup -c lib.config.js",
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "svelte": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist/router.umd.min.js"
    ],
}
```

`src/index.js`

```js
import SLink from './SLink.svelte';
import SView from './SView.svelte';

export { SLink, SView };
```

`rollup-plugin-svelte` will pick up the `svelte` field in your lib's `package.json`, so that import of Svelte components resolve correctly.

Comment: This does seem to be on the right track, but then the imports don't work as `../logic` is compiled to `umd`

Comment: You should import from the uncompiled source file, so it goes in the right bundle with the rest. `import { ... } from './logic.js'` or something like this, with a `src/logic.js` file.

Comment: I decided to compile all Typescript files into a `dist` folder with a script that also copies the components, point `main` and `svelte` to a single `index.js` which exports everything and this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I recently ran into this problem. I was setting up a new page and forgot the `defer` keyword on the `script`. I had:

```
<script src="/app/public/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

and it needed to be

```
<script defer src="/app/public/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

Notice the missing `defer`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your issue but I was getting the same error message for this reason:
In the `template.html` file located in the `src` folder, I removed the element that has the `#sapper` ID and replaced the `%sapper.html%` code inside the body tag. The next thing to do was to change the render target to the `document.body`, in the `client.js` file located in the `src` folder. I forgot to do this step and this was causing that error message.